# Ionic and sails.js (backend) test

Tags: iphone, angularjs, sails.js, ionic-framework

first I have to say I apologize for my bad English.

I tried testing ionic app on iphone but server side don't accept post data from iphone(ionic). 
I don't understand how to solve this. I need your help.

error messages is below.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (login, line 0) http://localhost:1337/user/login
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (register-device-token, line 0) https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/register-device-token
```

this is ionic code of service.js

```
factory('AuthenticationService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function($http, $q, localStorageService){

  function loginUser(post){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('http://localhost:1337/user/login', post)
    .success(function (data) {
      if (data.error || !data.user) {
        deferred.reject(data.error);
      }

      localStorageService.set('user', data.user);
      user = data.user;

      deferred.resolve(data.user);
    })
    .error(function () {
      deferred.reject('error');
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    login: loginUser
  };
}])
```

and controller.js is here.

```
  // inside of controller.js
  AuthenticationService.login(user).then(function (result){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $state.go('app.profile');
  }, function (error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log('error', error);
  });
```

↓
route of sails.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
  ......

  'POST /user/login': {
    controller: 'LoginController',
    action: 'create',
    cors: true
  },

  ......
}
```

LoginController.js of sails.js

```
create: function(req, res) {
  'use strict';
  sails.log.debug('create user method in');

  var user = req.params,
      uuid = NodeUuid.v4();

  sails.log.debug('user = ' + JSON.stringify(user));
  // Validator.validateUserInfo(user);
  User.create({
    //画面からの入力情報
  }).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code == 11000) {
        StatusService.returnResponse(res, Constants.statusCode.BadRequest, err, Constants.message.error.alreadyExistsEmail);
      }
    } else {
      StatusService.returnResponse(res, Constants.statusCode.OK, null, '');
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace this: `http://localhost:1337/user/login`

With your PC's local IP address(you can find your ip address by typing ipconfig in cmd)

```
http://yourIP:1337/user/login
```

also make sure that your pc and your mobile device is connected to the same wifi.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Matan. it works now! I appreciate your kind advice. Thank you again.